# What is the difference between paddingBottom and paddingEnd in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I understand the difference between padding and margin, but I don't understand the difference between those two pairs of attributes: bottom and end and on the other hand start and top.
[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SIZZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear: your TextView has a bound and padding is distance from the bound to the context (where text is rendered)
[image]

In the picture, padding is green area.

- paddingTop is upper distance
- paddingBottom is down distance
- paddingStart is right distance if rtl is enabled, otherwise it's left
  distance
- paddingEnd is left distance if rtl is enabled, otherwise
  it's right distance